# Java not found for Tabula-py with chaquopy inside an Android Studio Kotlin project

Tags: python, java, android, chaquopy, tabula-py

I am using chaqoupy and building an android app in kotlin using python scripts. I am trying to use the tabula-py module however I am getting java not found exception in my Logcat

```
com.chaquo.python.PyException: JavaNotFoundError: `java` command is not found from this Python process.Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for `java`
```

I have set the JAVA_HOME correctly and everything. Here is my python script

```py
import tabula
from io import BytesIO
def main(pdf_data):

    tables = tabula.read_pdf(BytesIO(pdf_data))
    tables = str(tables)
    return tables
```

Ive tried changing JAVA_HOME paths, reinstalled JDK. Tried adding a JRE to my Android Studio Project, tried changing to embedded JDK in my gradle settings.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the things you've mentioned will provide a `java` command on the Android device or emulator itself. Android does not come with such a command, and neither does Chaquopy. You may be able to use Termux instead.